# How to access other model's attribute in one model via Foreign key in django?

Tags: django, django-models

```
class Grade(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(u'年级', max_length=64)
    school = models.ForeignKey('School', verbose_name=u'学校')

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

class Class(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(u'班级', max_length=64)
    grade = models.ForeignKey('Grade', verbose_name=u'年级', related_name='grade')

    def getGradeName(self):
        return self.grade.name

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

class Student(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(u'姓名', max_length=64)
    sex = models.CharField(u'性别', max_length=64)
    id_num = models.CharField(u'身份证号', max_length=64)
    student_num = models.CharField(u'学号', max_length=64)
    class_id = models.ForeignKey('Class', verbose_name=u'班级', related_name='class_id')
    grade = class_id.name

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name
```

I want to get students'class'grade and then assign it to grade in Model Student.

How to get Grade's name in model Student?

Answer (score 1):

Since `grade` is going to be that of the `Class` instance of `Student`, I would suggest removing the `grade` class variable from `Student` and instead adding a [property](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#property) to the class `Student`. Like this.

```
class Student(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(u'姓名', max_length=64)
    sex = models.CharField(u'性别', max_length=64)
    id_num = models.CharField(u'身份证号', max_length=64)
    student_num = models.CharField(u'学号', max_length=64)
    class_id = models.ForeignKey('Class', verbose_name=u'班级', related_name='class_id')

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

    @property
    def grade_name(self):
        return self.class.grade.name
```

And to get the `grade` of a `Student` instance, it would be

```
student = Student.object.all()[0]
grade = student.grade_name
```

Comment: Where to add ```student = Student.object.all()[0]
grade = student.grade_name```

Comment: But I want to display in ```class StudentAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):list_display = ['name','sex','id_num', 'student_num','class_id']```

Answer (score 0):

```
#get first student in table 
s = Student.object.all()[0]
# get Grade access through Class model
print s.class_id.grade
```

Comment: In Model Student?

Comment: Please avoid giving code-only answers. Try to explain how your code solves OP's problem. Others who find this question may not have as much experience as you; help them understand.